# Do I need to invalidate/release the timer?

Tags: ios, multithreading, memory, memory-management, nstimer

In one of my view controllers code I have this line:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingOnce) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

which is called after 7 seconds and does something... (I don't assign the timer to a variable or property)

What happens if the view controller is released before the 7 seconds are over?

Do I have to release and/or invalidate the Timer at some point (i.e. in dealloc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of timer is retained only by the run loop. Since you don't have a pointer to it, you can't `invalidate` it. It also is going to retain its target (`self`), so it's not possible for `self` to deallocate prior to the timer firing. After it fires, the run loop will release it, so it will deallocate, causing it to release `self`, and allowing that object to deallocate (assuming there are no other retains on it).

In most case I do not recommend ignoring the return value from  `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:…` because it makes it impossible for you to `invalidate` the timer. But if that behavior is exactly what you want (sometimes in global timers created in AppDelegate), then it will work fine with no additional code.

Comment: To be clear: He *can* invalidate the timer, but only if he gets a reference to it.  It is possible to call `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` and ignore the `NSTimer` object that the method returns.  But OP could also assign the returned NSTimer to an ivar.  He just needs to be careful to avoid the retain loop: view controller <-> timer.

Comment: @RobNapier: If using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval is not the recommended way, Then what is the correct way to handle this scenario?

Comment: @MohnishHirudkar Sorry, I never updated the answer to match Aaron's comments. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

You should assign the timer to a variable and then in your view controller's `viewWillDisappear` (or `viewDidDisappear` maybe) method you can explicitly invalidate the timer and reassign the variable to nil.  Since you don't want this timer repeating anyway you may also want to assign the timer to nil at the end of your `doSomething` method.

The fact that the timer retains its target will prevent your view controller from being deallocated before the seven seconds are up, but will not prevent the view controller from getting the usual appearance related messages.

For example, you might do something like this:

```
_doSomethingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingOnce) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
// The rest of whatever method this is in.
…

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_doSomethingTimer invalidate];
    _doSomethingTimer = nil;
}
```